# Want to return only 1 cell in uitablelview but due to json response multiple cells are getting displayed

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, xcode, uitableview

I'm having an array of data that is being retrieved from a JSON. Storing that data into modal of struct. Also, I have a `UITableView` to display that data.The problem is that I'm getting multiple entity of response but want to show only one cell at a time. By returning 1 in `numberOfRowsInSection` is not working.

If I return 1 in `numberOfRowsInSection` then it gives an error

> index out of bound exception

Comment: show your code so we can help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

suppose you are storing your response in array named `arrResponseData` then you need to write your code like this to achieve your desired result.

You were getting index of bound issue because your tableview gets loaded before you store data in array and compiler do not get any index, so it fails with `index out of bound`

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if(arrResponseData && arrResponseData.count>0) {
        return 1
    } else {
        return 0
    }
}
```

Comment: @Suhail If this solution helped you as expected, then it deserves an upvote too! :)

Comment: How stupid was I to not to give a condition in that method!!! Thanks a ton. It helped me a lot.